# Excel VBA function unintentionally calls another function in module

Tags: vba, excel

This is probably a quick fix, but I am new to VBA and I'm somewhat confused. I have a module:

```
Function classify (r As Range)
Debug.Print("Text")
End Function

Function foo(r As Range)
Debug.Print(r.Count)
End Function
```

There is working code before and after the module.

If, in a cell in excel, I write `=foo(A1)` and then press enter, I get the following output:

```
 1 
Text
```

Why? How did foo call classify? Moreover, if I just call '=classify(A1)', I get

```
Text
Text
```

Has classify somehow been set to always get called? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: do you have a formula in A1 which is perhaps making other cells volatile?

Comment: Do you clear the output before you press enter? Maybe there are old values in the output pane that still show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way that I could reproduce your issue was with the following scenario:

```
Cell A1:
=foo(A1)

Cell A2:
=classify(A1)
```

When updating cell A1 I get

```
1
Text
```

I think this is due to the fact that Cell A2 has a reference to A1 so by updating A1 I also call the formula in A2 as it is referencing A1.

Assuming your formula that you are entering is in A1 I would trace dependents to see where the other formula is.